# Intellij IDEA 13 - Can't open Project Structure dialog anymore

Tags: intellij-idea, dialog, window, show, project-structure

as already described in title, i'm not able to open the **project structure** dialog window in intellij anymore.

neither the shortcut (**Ctrl+alt+shift+s**) nor the menu element under **File -> Project Structure** nor the little button in the upper right corner do work.

Clarification: Menu element :

[image]

This "bug" occured suddenly as I wrote a web (vaadin/maven) project and tried to set up glassfish, where i often had to switch to the project structure dialog.

Since the first occurence i *wasn't* able to fix it by restarting intellij or switching projects.

This also happened on my laptop running the same intellij and windows version (*Ultimate 13.0.1 Build: 133.331* on Windows 7 x64)

i appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you tried right-click on your project in Project view (Alt+1) and then "Open module settings" (F4)?

Comment: @JakubK yes just did that... it does not work aswell :(

Comment: Do you found anything interesting in Idea log?

Comment: good idea to look there @JakubK! I really found something concerning my problem: a full stacktrace is here - http://pastebin.com/iELvZLuM
the **lines 55** and **150**: _ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - Last Action:_ **ShowProjectStructureSettings** tell me it must have something to do with the opening of the dialog..
but i'm sorry, i cant interprete it by myself to find an answer :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your log shows that it is a bug in IntelliJ IDEA - they are trying to create file passing null pathname. Try to delete project files and reopen project from scratch (maybe you've lost some file) - if it won't help then you should create an issue here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/ - You can even copy-paste text from your question and attach stacktrace

Comment: kinda late, but was very busy @ university.
i followed ur idea to reopen from scratch, i really just killed the physical files and checked out from git again... project structure dialog works again.. im kinda happy, but still confused why that'd happen!
thank you for your help!

ill post a bug report to jetbrains anyways, maybe it can improve their project ;)

Answer (score 5):

This also happened to me, but removing new plugins etc didn't help.

Nor did nuking my project and rebuilding it from scratch.

In the end I deleted all caches, restarted Intellij and at last I could access the project settings again!  By the way, I'm using Intellij 11.1 - mainly because I can't get 13 to start up, but that's another story

Comment: `File` -> `Invalidate Cache / Restart...` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue...upon further inspection in the log dump...I noticed the following:

ERROR - llij.ide.plugins.PluginManager - com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.FileChooserDescriptor.setTitle(Ljava/lang/String;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.openapi.fileChooser.FileChooserDescriptor.setTitle(Ljava/lang/String;)V
 at com.jetbrains.python.sdk.PythonSdkType.getHomeChooserDescriptor(PythonSdkType.java:247)

Disabled the latest Python Plugin and restarted and everything is working normal again.

I remembered I had recently update my python plugin and am not using it presently so I was able to disable it without issue.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me. The comment above helped.  I had just added some plugins.  Disabled them and it started working again. Not sure exactly which one because I disabled all 4 -- Bean Validation Support, Bitbucket, Jelastic Cloud Platform Integration, and Quick Notes.

Answer (score 0):

For me it has been resolved by switching off FindBugs plugin and restart IDEA. So Project Structure is available for me now.

Answer (score 0):

One of the plugins might be causing it. To disable a plugin, go here: 
[image]

You'll know for sure if a plugin is bad if you see this Exclamation picture: 
[image]

Clicking on it will bring up a pop-up. To disable the plugin, click on this: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me it got resolved just by restarting the intelliJ IDEA. I'm using intelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2018.1 edition.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

Press Shift twice and type Restore default settings. Click Restore and Restart.